# Inbuilt functions in linux terminal

Tags: c

*Why "strrev()" and some other inbuilt string functions in c doesn't work in terminal?*

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
char c[50];
scanf("%s",c);
strrev(c);
printf("%s",c)
}
```

Comment: 1. `strrev()` is not a standard function and is not available under gcc compiler.
2. Also you are using it wrong, in most cases `strrev()` returns a pointer to a string. This doesn't really matter as long as you have to give your own implementation of it.

Comment: It's not available because it's not standard nor is it built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strrev` is not standard, but can be easily implemented

```
void strrev(char *s) {
    int i,n = strlen(s);
    for(i=n/2 ; i>=0 ; i--) {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }
}
```